Material works like light & lights up surrounded objects
The material of the floor and the walls work like light and I have no idea why.



You've plugged the ColorRamp directly into the Output, which makes it work as if there was an Emission node, if you don't want that put a Diffuse node or a Principled BSDF node before the Output.
